# Fixtures' references disapearing after one test

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, phpunit

In my LoadFixture.php, I add reference to all my fixtures like this :

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager) {
    $user = new user("Dummy");
    $this->persist($user);
    $this->addReference("user", $user);
}
```

In my test class I load them like this :

```
public function setUp() {
        if(self::$do_setup){
            $this->loadFixtures(array(
                "Bundle\\Tests\\Fixtures\\LoadUser"
            )) ;
        }
}
```

In my tests I use them like this :

```
public function testOne() {
    $client = $this->createClient($this->getReference("user_a"));
    $client->request('GET', '/');
    $this->assertStatusCode(200, $client);
    self::$do_setup=false;
}

public function testTwo() {
    $client = $this->createClient($this->getReference("user_a"));
    $client->request('GET', '/home');
    $this->assertStatusCode(200, $client);
}
```

The thing is, technically, I dont need to use `setUp()` for each test, so I use `$do_setup` and a `if` to execute `setUp` if needed.

But if I dont execute the `setUp()` in my `testTwo`, while my fixtures are in my database,  `$this->getReference("user_a")` is giving me an error :

```
Call to a member function getReferenceRepository() on a non-object
```

**How can I solve that ?**

**UPDATE**
I have found a solution. So I post it here, just in case someone face the same problem as me.
Many thanks to @Damien Flament for his answer, regarding the fact that the TestCase is deleted after each test.

I changed the name of my `setUp()` method to `open()`, and my `tearDown()` method to `close()`.
The first method of the class call the `open()` method, and now return `$this`.
The next method is annoted `@depends testOne` and take a parameter.
With this parameter I can use my references again.
Ex :

```
// new setUp Metod
public function open() {
        if(self::$do_setup){
            $this->loadFixtures(array(
                "Bundle\\Tests\\Fixtures\\LoadUser"
            )) ;
        }
}
//new tearDown method
public function close() {
   $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getConnection()->close();
}
public function testOne() {
    $this->open();
    $client = $this->createClient($this->getReference("user_a"));
    $client->request('GET', '/');
    $this->assertStatusCode(200, $client);
    return $this;
}
/**
 * @depends testOne
 */
public function testTwo($it) {
    $client = $this->createClient($it->getReference("user_a"));
    $client->request('GET', '/home');
    $this->assertStatusCode(200, $client);
    return $it;
}
/**
 * @depends testTwo
 */
public function testThree($it) {
    $client = $this->createClient($it->getReference("user_a"));
    $client->request('GET', '/about');
    $this->assertStatusCode(200, $client);
    $this->close();
}
```

Comment: Please edit and update your original question ("Trouble generating reference of Doctrine's fixtures in static context") instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the *TestCase* object is deleted and recreated by PHPUnit (I didn't read the PHPUnit source code, but I think it's the more easy way to reset the testing environment for each test).

So your object (probably referenced by a test class object attribute) is probably garbage collected.

To setup fixture once per test class, use the *TestCase::setUpBeforeClass()* method.

See [documention on "Sharing fixtures"](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.0/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.sharing-fixture).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I use a special class to construct my fixtures. So I would not be able to use in a `setUpBeforeClass` method.

Comment: I have found a solution and edited my original post, thanks for mentionning the fact that the TestCase object is deleted and recreated by PHPUnit.